# Can't mount a volume when running a docker image

Tags: windows, docker, mount, docker-volume

I'm using a docker image to start up a container using this command.

`docker run --rm -it ghcr.io/airboxlab/rllib-energyplus:v0.3_energyplus23.2_ray2.8 --mount D:\Projects\Masters\Docker\rllib-energyplus:/rllib-energyplus`

I would expect it to start a container and then mount a volume with the directory I specified. When I run the command a container is built from the image as I would expect. **However**, there is no volumes. I'm using windows 11.

Any advice?

Comment: [`docker run ... --mount ...` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount) does not necessarily create a volume; it can also mount a `tmpfs` (ephemeral) or a host directory. How did you check that the directory was not mounted?

Comment: So I have used both '-v' and '--mount' and neither work. I used the command 'docker inspect -f "{{ .Mounts }}" containerid' (I added the actual container ID in the command fyi) to check in terminal which returned '[]' and I can also see in docker desktop UI and the docker extension for VS Code that there was no volume created.

Comment: `docker run` options like `--mount` (or the shorter `-v`) need to come _before_ the image name.  Anything _after_ the image name is interpreted as the main container command.

Comment: can you make that an answer @DavidMaze so it's easier for others to find in the future?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you! That solved my issue, I can now see a mount.